# setMyLocationEnabled() Google Maps error?

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm just trying to enable the My Location button on google maps, but the app keeps crashing when I add this:

googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true)

To the method which displays Google maps

Here is my code:

```
    package com.example.safezone;
    import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationClient;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
    import android.view.View;


public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    GoogleMap mMap;
     LatLng myPosition;
     LocationClient mLocationClient;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void mapSearch(View v) {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);

    }

    public void myLocation(View v) {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_location);
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    }     
}
```

Errors:

```
11-25 14:42:27.865: E/AndroidRuntime(3521): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-25 14:42:27.865: E/AndroidRuntime(3521): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
11-25 14:42:27.865: E/AndroidRuntime(3521):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3691)
11-25 14:42:27.865: E/AndroidRuntime(3521):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4211)
11-25 14:42:27.865: E/AndroidRuntime(3521):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17267)
11-25 14:42:27.865: E/AndroidRuntime(3521):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
11-25 14:42:27.865: E/AndroidRuntime(3521):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-25 14:42:27.865: E/AndroidRuntime(3521):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-25 14:42:27.865: E/AndroidRuntime(3521):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
11-25 14:42:27.865: E/AndroidRuntime(3521):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-25 14:42:27.865: E/AndroidRuntime(3521):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-25 14:42:27.865: E/AndroidRuntime(3521):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
11-25 14:42:27.865: E/AndroidRuntime(3521):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
11-25 14:42:27.865: E/AndroidRuntime(3521):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-25 14:42:27.865: E/AndroidRuntime(3521): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
11-25 14:42:27.865: E/AndroidRuntime(3521):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-25 14:42:27.865: E/AndroidRuntime(3521):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-25 14:42:27.865: E/AndroidRuntime(3521):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3686)
11-25 14:42:27.865: E/AndroidRuntime(3521):     ... 11 more
11-25 14:42:27.865: E/AndroidRuntime(3521): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-25 14:42:27.865: E/AndroidRuntime(3521):     at com.example.safezone.MainActivity.myLocation(MainActivity.java:31)
11-25 14:42:27.865: E/AndroidRuntime(3521):     ... 14 more
```

The method executes fine if I don't add setMyLocationEnabled(), and Google Maps comes up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your variable `mMap` is null. You have not assigned any object instance to it. Based on your layout xml, you need to assign value to it or initialise it.

Answer (score 0):

it is crashing because you did not get the map so your `mMap` object is null when you try to access it

```
mMap = getSupportFragmentManager().findFagmentById(r.id.yourfragment).getMap();
```